# split strings on first and last commas

Tags: regex, string, r, split

I would like to split strings on the first and last comma.  Each string has at least two
commas.  Below is an example data set and the desired result.

A similar question here asked how to split on the first comma: [Split on first comma in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10309122/split-on-first-comma-in-string)

Here I asked how to split strings on the first two colons: [Split string on first two colons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19749546/split-string-on-first-two-colons)

Thank you for any suggestions.  I prefer a solution in base R.  Sorry if this is a duplicate.

```
my.data <- read.table(text='

my.string        some.data
123,34,56,78,90     10
87,65,43,21         20
a4,b6,c8888         30
11,bbbb,ccccc       40
uu,vv,ww,xx         50
j,k,l,m,n,o,p       60', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

desired.result <- read.table(text='

 my.string1 my.string2 my.string3 some.data
        123   34,56,78         90        10
         87      65,43         21        20
         a4         b6      c8888        30
         11       bbbb      ccccc        40
         uu      vv,ww         xx        50
          j  k,l,m,n,o          p        60', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a relatively simple approach.  In the first line we use `sub` to replace the first and last commas with semicolons producing `s`.  Then we read `s` using `sep=";"` and finally `cbind` the rest of `my.data` to it:

```
s <- sub(",(.*),", ";\\1;", my.data[[1]])
DF <- read.table(text=s, sep =";", col.names=paste0("mystring",1:3), as.is=TRUE)
cbind(DF, my.data[-1])
```

giving:

```
  mystring1 mystring2 mystring3 some.data
1       123  34,56,78        90        10
2        87     65,43        21        20
3        a4        b6     c8888        30
4        11      bbbb     ccccc        40
5        uu     vv,ww        xx        50
6         j k,l,m,n,o         p        60
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `\K` operator which keeps text already matched out of the result and a negative look ahead assertion to do this (well *almost*, there is an annoying comma at the start of the middle portion which I am yet to get rid of in the `strsplit`). But I enjoyed this as an exercise in constructing a regex...

```
x <- '123,34,56,78,90'
strsplit( x , "^[^,]+\\K|,(?=[^,]+$)" , perl = TRUE )
#[[1]]
#[1] "123"       ",34,56,78" "90"
```

---

#### Explantion:

- `^[^,]+` : from the start of the string match one or more characters that are *not* a `,`
- `\\K` : but don't include those matched characters in the match
- So the first match is the first comma...
- `|` : or you can match...
- `,(?=[^,]+$)` : a `,` so long as it is followed by [`(?=...)`] one or more characters that *are not* a `,` until the end of the string (`$`)...

Comment: +1, but you're missing a `,` after the `\K`, as he doesn't want the splitting `,` in the match. I'd suggest changing the regex to `^[^,]+\K,|,(?=[^,]+$)` or `^\w+\K,|,(?=\w+$)`

Comment: @zx81 try it. You won't get what you are expecting. Think of it this way - Q: if you add the comma you suggest, how many of the comma's will then match the regex? A: All of them! Your other suggestion will also not do what you expect.

Comment: Simon, I had tried it. The second solution I gave you is the one I had come up with independently, and I didn't want to post it in order not to compete with you because the solutions were so close. Here's the [demo](http://regex101.com/r/sC6tP9), you can see that it only matches the right commas. And here's a [demo of your one](http://regex101.com/r/bA2oA1) with the additional comma I am suggesting.

Comment: @zx81 let me be more specific - try it in R. I can't figure out why it won't work as you expect, but it doesn't. Must be something to do with greedy matching. I do not doubt that you came up with it independently at all btw!

Comment: @zx81 that is actually quite wierd... using `m <- gregexpr( '^\\w+\\K,|,(?=\\w+$)' , x , perl = TRUE );regmatches( x , m )` shows the desired matches are returned; the two and only two commas per line, (where `x` is a character vector of the strings in your demo).

Comment: Simon, glad you're able to test it in R, because I can't do that directly at the moment. I had only tested it with RegexBuddy in R mode. Sounds like you found the magic moves to make it work. :) Btw for that regex, the R code suggested by RB was `strsplit(subject, "^\\w+\\K,|,(?=\\w+$)", perl=TRUE);`

Comment: @zx81 I've actually had to ask [a question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23969411/1478381) because I can't work out why `strsplit` does not give the desired result.

Comment: @SimonO'Hanlon  I want to give you the check mark, but I cannot with that one comma still present.  I know you posted a follow-up question.  Might the answer to your post help to get rid of the comma?  All of the answers deserve the check mark, but yours looks very nice.

Answer (score 1):

Here is code to split on the first and last comma.  This code draws heavily from an answer by @bdemarest here: [Split string on first two colons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19749546/split-string-on-first-two-colons)  The `gsub` pattern below, which is the meat of the answer, contains important differences.  The code for creating the new data frame after strings are split is the same as that of @bdemarest

```
# Replace first and last commas with colons.

new.string <- gsub(pattern="(^[^,]+),(.+),([^,]+$)", 
              replacement="\\1:\\2:\\3", x=my.data$my.string)
new.string

# Split on colons
split.data <- strsplit(new.string, ":")

# Create data frame
new.data <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, split.data))
names(new.data) <- paste("my.string", seq(ncol(new.data)), sep="")

my.data$my.string <- NULL
my.data <- cbind(new.data, my.data)
my.data

#   my.string1 my.string2 my.string3 some.data
# 1        123   34,56,78         90        10
# 2         87      65,43         21        20
# 3         a4         b6      c8888        30
# 4         11       bbbb      ccccc        40
# 5         uu      vv,ww         xx        50
# 6          j  k,l,m,n,o          p        60



# Here is code for splitting strings on the first comma

my.data <- read.table(text='

my.string        some.data
123,34,56,78,90     10
87,65,43,21         20
a4,b6,c8888         30
11,bbbb,ccccc       40
uu,vv,ww,xx         50
j,k,l,m,n,o,p       60', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)


# Replace first comma with colon

new.string <- gsub(pattern="(^[^,]+),(.+$)", 
                   replacement="\\1:\\2", x=my.data$my.string)
new.string

# Split on colon
split.data <- strsplit(new.string, ":")

# Create data frame
new.data <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, split.data))
names(new.data) <- paste("my.string", seq(ncol(new.data)), sep="")

my.data$my.string <- NULL
my.data <- cbind(new.data, my.data)
my.data

#   my.string1  my.string2 some.data
# 1        123 34,56,78,90        10
# 2         87    65,43,21        20
# 3         a4    b6,c8888        30
# 4         11  bbbb,ccccc        40
# 5         uu    vv,ww,xx        50
# 6          j k,l,m,n,o,p        60




# Here is code for splitting strings on the last comma

my.data <- read.table(text='

my.string        some.data
123,34,56,78,90     10
87,65,43,21         20
a4,b6,c8888         30
11,bbbb,ccccc       40
uu,vv,ww,xx         50
j,k,l,m,n,o,p       60', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)


# Replace last comma with colon

new.string <- gsub(pattern="^(.+),([^,]+$)", 
                   replacement="\\1:\\2", x=my.data$my.string)
new.string

# Split on colon
split.data <- strsplit(new.string, ":")

# Create new data frame
new.data <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, split.data))
names(new.data) <- paste("my.string", seq(ncol(new.data)), sep="")

my.data$my.string <- NULL
my.data <- cbind(new.data, my.data)
my.data

#     my.string1 my.string2 some.data
# 1 123,34,56,78         90        10
# 2     87,65,43         21        20
# 3        a4,b6      c8888        30
# 4      11,bbbb      ccccc        40
# 5     uu,vv,ww         xx        50
# 6  j,k,l,m,n,o          p        60
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a simple `strsplit` here on that column

```
popshift<-sapply(strsplit(my.data$my.string,","), function(x) 
    c(x[1], paste(x[2:(length(x)-1)],collapse=","), x[length(x)]))

desired.result <- cbind(data.frame(my.string=t(popshift)), my.data[-1])
```

I just split up all the values and make a new vector with the first, last and middle strings. Then i cbind that with the rest of the data. The result is

```
  my.string.1 my.string.2 my.string.3 some.data
1         123    34,56,78          90        10
2          87       65,43          21        20
3          a4          b6       c8888        30
4          11        bbbb       ccccc        40
5          uu       vv,ww          xx        50
6           j   k,l,m,n,o           p        60
```

Comment: @MarkMiller -- Ahh, but that `","` **is** a (very simple) `regex`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `str_match()` from package `stringr`, and a little help from one of your links,

```
> library(stringr)
> data.frame(str_match(my.data$my.string, "(.+?),(.*),(.+?)$")[,-1], 
             some.data = my.data$some.data)
#    X1        X2    X3 some.data
# 1 123  34,56,78    90        10
# 2  87     65,43    21        20
# 3  a4        b6 c8888        30
# 4  11      bbbb ccccc        40
# 5  uu     vv,ww    xx        50
# 6   j k,l,m,n,o     p        60
```