# string split on last comma in R

Tags: r, string, split

I'm not new to R but I am relatively new to regular expressions.

A similar question can be found in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10309122/split-on-first-comma-in-string), but it asks to split on the first comma rather than the last one.

As an example, if I use

```
> lastcomma_strsplit("UK, USA, Germany", ", ")
[[1]]
[1] "UK"      "USA"     "Germany"
```

I want to get

```
[[1]]
[1] "UK, USA"     "Germany"
```

And if I use

```
> lastcomma_strsplit("London, Washington, D.C., Berlin", ", ")
[[1]]
[1] "London"     "Washington" "D.C."       "Berlin"
```

I want to get

```
[[1]]
[1] "London, Washington, D.C."       "Berlin"
```

One viable way I think is to replace the last comma by something else such as

```
$, #, *, ...
```

then use

```
strsplit()
```

to split the string by the one you replaced (Make sure it is unique!), but I'm more happy if you can deal with the problem using some built in function directly.

So how can I do that?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
strsplit("UK, USA, Germany", ",(?=[^,]+$)", perl=TRUE)

## [[1]]
## [1] "UK, USA" " Germany"
```

You may want:

```
strsplit("UK, USA, Germany", ",\\s*(?=[^,]+$)", perl=TRUE)

## [[1]]
## [1] "UK, USA" "Germany"
```

As it will match if there is no space after the comma:

```
strsplit(c("UK, USA, Germany", "UK, USA,Germany"), ",\\s*(?=[^,]+$)", perl=TRUE)

## [[1]]
## [1] "UK, USA" "Germany"
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] "UK, USA" "Germany"
```

Comment: Thanks, this is OK, but you didn't take the second comma away...       it is much better to remove the second comma.

Comment: Thank you very much, mate! Any suggestion or websites to learn basics of regular expression in R?

Comment: Two places: I pick up a lot here on SO and http://www.regular-expressions.info/rlanguage.html

Answer (score 8):

You can use `stri_split` function from `stringi` package

```
x <- "USA,UK,Poland"
stri_split_fixed(x,",") # standard split by comma
[[1]]
[1] "USA"    "UK"     "Poland"

stri_split_fixed(x,",",n = 2) # set the max number of elements
[[1]]
[1] "USA"       "UK,Poland"
```

Unfortunately there is no parameter to change the starting point for splitting (from begin/end) but we can handle this another way - using `stri_reverse`

```
stri_split_fixed(stri_reverse(x),",",n = 2) #reverse
[[1]]
[1] "dnaloP" "KU,ASU"

stri_reverse(stri_split_fixed(stri_reverse(x),",",n = 2)[[1]]) #reverse back
[1] "Poland" "USA,UK"
stri_reverse(stri_split_fixed(stri_reverse(x),",",n = 2)[[1]])[2:1] #and again :)
[1] "USA,UK" "Poland"
```