# Replace part of value in a given column of data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this:

```
TAGNAME                                  VALUE
XX:YY:ZZ:WXYX:title_for_this.and_that_a   20.2
PP:YY:ZZ:ABCF:title_for_this.and_that_b   45.7
QQ:YY:ZZ:FGHJ:title_for_this.and_that_c   27.2
RR:YY:ZZ:JYHG:title_for_this.and_that_d   30.9
```

I need to remove all the characters from TAGNAME that occur before the last colon. So what I need it this:

```
TAGNAME                     VALUE
title_for_this.and_that_a    20.2
title_for_this.and_that_b    45.7
title_for_this.and_that_c    27.2
title_for_this.and_that_d    30.9
```

I can get all the characters before the last colon using:

```
tagnames <- sapply(strsplit(data_frame$TAGNAME, "\\:[^\\:]*$"), "[", 1)
```

I tried to use this to gsub the characters out from the TAGNAME like this:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(data_frame)) {
   data_frame[i,1] <- gsub(data_frame[i,1], tagnames[i],'')
 }
```

which, besides being an awful way to loop through a data frame, doesn't work.

Comment: I get 'subscript out of bounds' when using this

Comment: I didnt test it to be honest but have a [look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24938616/string-split-on-last-comma-in-r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df$TAGNAME = sub(".*:","", df$TAGNAME)
```

explaination of the regex ".*:"
. select any character  * present 0 or more times before :
See [this website](http://regexr.com/) for additional information on regex.

Comment: If you'd like, please add some help on how the greedy regex works.