# split string last delimiter

Tags: r, string, split, delimiter

I need help figuring out how to split strings in a column of a data frame based on the last delimiter when I have varying numbers of the same delimiter in R. For example,

```
col1 <- c('a', 'b', 'c')
col2 <- c('a_b', 'a_b_c', 'a_b_c_d')
df <- data.frame(cbind(col1, col2))
```

And I would like to split df$col2 to have a data frame that looks like:

```
col1 <- c('a', 'b', 'c')
col2 <- c('a', 'a_b', 'a_b_c')
col3 <- c('b', 'c', 'd')
```

Comment: As an aside, don't ever do `data.frame(cbind(...` unless you want your life to be difficult. That creates a matrix first, then a data.frame and changes everything to one type (numbers to characters for instance). Just `data.frame(...` will do.

Comment: Thank you @thelatemail. I'm obviously learning, so every piece of advice helps.

Comment: Possible duplicate questions too - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24938616/string-split-on-last-comma-in-r and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31774086/extracting-text-after-last-period-in-string-in-r

Comment: None of those really have a good answer for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These use no packages.  They assume that each element of `col2` has at least one underscore.  (See note if lifting this restriction is needed.)

**1)** The first regular expression `(.*)_` matches everything up to the last underscore followed by everything remaining `.*` and the first `sub` replaces the entire match with the matched part within parens.   This works because such matches are greedy so the first `.*` will take everything it can leaving the rest for the second `.*` .  The second regular expression matches everything up to the last underscore and the second `sub` replaces that with the empty string.

```
transform(df, col2 = sub("(.*)_.*", "\\1", col2), col3 = sub(".*_", "", col2))
```

**2)** Here is a variation that is a bit more symmetric.  It uses the same regular expression for both `sub` calls.

```
pat <- "(.*)_(.*)"
transform(df, col2 = sub(pat, "\\1", col2), col3 = sub(pat, "\\2", col2))
```

**Note:** If we did want to handle strings with no underscore at all such that "xyz" is split into "xyz" and "" then use this for the second `sub`.  It tries to match the left hand side of the | first and if that fails (which will occur if there are no underscores) then the entire string will match the right hand side and `sub` will replace that with the empty string.

```
sub(".*_|^[^_]*$", "", col2)
```

Comment: Thank you @GGrothendieck, that works perfectly! [Though, it will take me a while to figure out what it all means.]

Answer (score 5):

Using the `stringi` package, you can also achieve your goal.`stri_extract_last_regex()` extract the last element of what you specify in a pattern. Here, I said "get the last small letter in a string." Likewise, you can use `stri_replace_last_regex()` to modify `col2`. Here I said "I want to replace the last pattern of _ and a small letter with nothing." That is, I said "I want to remove the last pattern of _ and a small letter."

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringi)

df %>%
mutate(col3 = stri_extract_last_regex(str = col2, pattern = "[a-z]"),
       col2 = stri_replace_last_regex(str = col2, pattern = "_[a-z]", replacement = ""))

#  col1  col2 col3
#1    a     a    b
#2    b   a_b    c
#3    c a_b_c    d
```

Answer (score 2):

A `strsplit` solution:

```
spl <- strsplit(as.character(df$col2), "_")

sapply(lapply(spl, head, -1), paste, collapse="_")
#[1] "a"     "a_b"   "a_b_c"
sapply(lapply(spl, tail, 1), paste, collapse="_")
#[1] "b" "c" "d"
```

Or go full functional crazy:

```
Map(
  function(spl,ty,n) sapply(spl, function(x) paste(ty(x,n),collapse="_") ),
  list(strsplit(as.character(df$col2), "_")),
  c(head,tail),
  c(-1,1) 
)
#[[1]]
#[1] "a"     "a_b"   "a_b_c"
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "b" "c" "d"
```