# How to split a string of characters by the first white space?

Tags: regex, r

I would like to split a column of names, into two columns by the first white space. In this example, we have two white spaces, but could be more.

```
a <- "Lucero del Alba"
```

**The expected outcome:**

```
> c
[1] "Lucero"   "del Alba"
```

**Approach 1**, wrong because is deleating "Lucero del" :

```
> strsplit("Lucero del Alba", "^.+ ")
[[1]]
[1] ""     "Alba"
```

**Approach 2**, good, but how do I get the rest?

```
> strsplit("Lucero del Alba", " .+$")
[[1]]
[1] "Lucero"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Splitting a string on the first space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8299978/splitting-a-string-on-the-first-space) but the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10309122/split-on-first-comma-in-string)  are better

Comment: Yes, I just found that, it is duplicated.

Comment: If you can control the number of splits, set it for 1 and just use [ ]+